# Software to recover audio recorder interrupted recording

Tags: audio-recording

I recorded a 1h interview, and my recorder shut down because of the batteries.

I have now a 0KB .wav file, but I'm unable to read it. Is it possible to recover it ? how is the process of writing a file without ending the flow ? Is the data present or am I losing my time trying to recover some part of the file content ?

Comment: What device is "recorder"? An answer depends on what device it is and what operating system it runs. Data may be present, but it may also not be.

Comment: A zoom h4n pro. I don't think there is an full os like, Maybe a firmware.

Comment: If the recording was saved to the SD-card then you could try to use photorec on the sd-card.